# How can I include 'quote inside a list in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, quote

I am trying to make a list in Scheme like this: (list 'quote 'a) and I expect the output to be (quote a) but the interpreter excutes the quote and the output is: 'a

How can I write the code to get the expected output?

Answer (score 4):

That's as it ought to be, since the expression `'a` is an abbreviation for the list `(quote a)`, and the interpreter's printer is using that shorthand for its output. You should note that if you tell the interpreter to evaluate `'a`, it prints out `a` unadorned with an apostrophe.

If you try taking out the parts of `(list 'quote 'a)`, you would see that you have exactly the list you expected to get:

```
> (car (list 'quote 'a))
quote
> (cadr (list 'quote 'a))
a
```

So in summary, you *are* getting the expected output, just not the expected representation. If you truly demand that you get as output `(quote a)`, then you have to look into your interpreter's documentation to see if that's supported. Or you might have to write your own procedure to print out lists.

Answer (score 0):

Which implementation are you using.  Changing how the REPL prints out sexps depends on your implementation of scheme, and if the implementation supports writing out sexps in an expanded form.